# Laravel - Enums decalred in a file with another class won't load until "main" class is called

Tags: php, enums

I have a file. Let's call it `Foo.php`. It looks like this:

```php
namespace App\Helpers;

enum FooTypes: string {
    case A = "A";
    case B = "B";
}

class Foo {

   const BAR = "Bar";
   // ...
}
```

This will work:

```php
use App\Helpers\{ Foo, FooTypes };

echo Foo::BAR;
echo FooTypes::A->value;
```

This will fail with a `"class FooTypes not found"` error:

```php
use App\Helpers\{ Foo, FooTypes };

// echo Foo::BAR;
echo FooTypes::A->value;
```

It looks like I ***have to*** use the "main" class `Foo` before I can use any of the enums decalred in the same file. But that seems kind of absurd. What is happening? How do I resolve this? I could maybe seperate the enum into a seperate file but it really doesn't make sense to me in my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `use` statement is purely a way to provide a short-hand within a particular file for a symbol (class, function, enum, etc) which is in a different namespace. See [Using namespaces: aliasing/importing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) in the PHP manual. It lets you type `echo FooTypes::A->value;` instead of `echo \App\Helpers\FooTypes::A->value;` but that is *all* it does.

This is completely unrelated to how the definition of a particular symbol is *loaded*. For that, you are probably relying on [autoloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), which runs a callback function *when a particular class / enum / etc is first used*. The callback function then generally includes a file defining that symbol.

To be completely clear, defining an alias for a symbol with a `use` statement, *does not* trigger the autoloader to be run. Only actually *executing code that needs that definition* will trigger the autoloader.

The most common convention is to put each definition into a separate file, and then configure the autoloader to load the file based on that name; but *that is just a convention*. If you want to have a different convention, e.g. that any name ending with "Types" is in the same file as the class without that ending, you can write an autoload function which implements that. For instance:

```php
function my_autoload_callback(string $nameToLoad): void {
    $filePath = PROJECT_ROOT . '/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $nameToLoad) . '.php';
    if ( file_exists($filePath) ) {
        require_once $filePath;
    }
    else {
        // try without "Types" on the end
        // should probably have another file_exists check here
        require_once str_replace('Types.php', '.php', $filePath);
        // we could check if this has found the right class
    }
    // if the function reaches here without loading the required class,
    //   you will get a "class not found" error from PHP
}
```

Note that the autoloader does not know whether it is looking for a class, an interface, a trait, or an enum; the only input you will get is the fully-qualified name, such as `"App\Helpers\FooTypes"`.

Comment: This is in the context of a laravel app, so yeah there's an autoloader. Thank you, marking this as correct as it's the more complete answer

Answer (score 2):

because `use` statement does not really "load" the file until you call what's in it,

when you call `Foo::BAR` it loads the file `App\Helpers\Foo.php` thus you able to use `FooTypes` which also from that file.

Here another example, it will work fine, but if you comment the 1st return statement, it will throw an error

```
// assume file is in app\Helpers\Foo.php
use \App\Helpers;

// this nonsense doesn't exist, but as long as its not called, theres no problem;
use \Something\That\Dont\Exist;

Route::get('/something', function() {    
    
    //Works Fine as it loads app\Helpers\Foo.php first and able to find FooTypes inside that file
    return [Helpers\Foo::BAR, Helpers\FooTypes::A];

     //trows an error because it tries to load app\Helpers\FooTypes.php first
    return [Helpers\FooTypes::A, Helpers\Foo::BAR];

});
```

Comment: so is there no way to have multiple classes in the same file and import them separately?

Comment: you can do that pretty easily if you are using `require` or `include`, like you can load the actual file in your app service providers, but if you rely on autoloading, you need to call something first that loads the actual file before you can use any other class inside the file.